# I'm having problems with the Javafx image dispay

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button

I'm working on a program for school where the user can select a radio button to display an image of a president. However I can't get the images to display when a button is clicked. I can't tell where it's going wrong and I need a little help. Everything else works just fine. Are there any edits I need to make?

```
package com.example.imagedisplay;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

public class PresidentImageDisplay extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        directoryChooser.setTitle("Select Presidents Folder");
        File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);

        if (selectedDirectory != null) {
            File[] imageFiles = selectedDirectory.listFiles();
            if (imageFiles != null && imageFiles.length >= 5) {
                ImageView[] presidentImageViews = new ImageView[5];

                ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
                HBox radioBox = new HBox(10);

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    presidentImageViews[i] = new ImageView(new Image(imageFiles[i].toURI().toString()));
                    presidentImageViews[i].setVisible(false);

                    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton("President " + (i + 1));
                    radioButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
                    final int index = i;
                    radioButton.setOnAction(event -> {
                        for (ImageView imageView : presidentImageViews) {
                            imageView.setVisible(false);
                        }
                        presidentImageViews[index].setVisible(true);
                    });

                    radioBox.getChildren().add(radioButton);
                }

                VBox root = new VBox(10);
                root.getChildren().addAll(radioBox);

                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
                primaryStage.setTitle("US Presidents");
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Folder must contain at least 5 image files.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: New detail, I also can't tell if the directory chooser can open the jpg images or not.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Do you need a lot of `ImageViews` or just one? I also do not see where you say anything like `parentNode.getchildren().add(imageView)`.

Comment: So what actually happens? Do you get an error? Can you tell if the action event handler is being invoked (maybe put a `System.out.println(...)` statement in there as a test)? Can you display one (or more) of the images without the radio buttons?

Answer (score 6):

Here are some issues with your code.

1. You don't use a filter. Use a filter so that only files with image extensions are selected.
2. You never add your `ImageViews` to the `Scene`.
3. Do you need multiple `ImageViews` or just one?

Here is a sample app that uses one `ImageView` to display multiple images.

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        directoryChooser.setTitle("Select Presidents Folder");
        File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(primaryStage);
        File[] imageFiles;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        
        if (selectedDirectory != null) 
        {
            //Use a filter to get the image files.
            imageFiles = selectedDirectory.listFiles((File dir, String name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".png") || 
                    name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".gif") ||
                    name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpeg") ||
                    name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mpo") ||
                    name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".tiff"));
            
            if (imageFiles != null && imageFiles.length >= 5) 
            {
                ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();
                VBox radioBox = new VBox(10);

                for (int i = 0; i < imageFiles.length; i++) {
                    Image image = new Image(imageFiles[i].toURI().toString());
                    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton("President " + (i + 1));
                    radioButton.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);                    
                    radioButton.setOnAction(event ->{
                        imageView.setImage(image);
                    });                   

                    radioBox.getChildren().add(radioButton);
                }                
                
                HBox root = new HBox(10);
                root.getChildren().addAll(radioBox, imageView);//Add the VBox and ImageView to the root node.
                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);
                primaryStage.setTitle("US Presidents");
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Folder must contain at least 5 image files.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]
**Image Info:**

- Artist: GraphicLoads - http://www.iconarchive.com/artist/graphicloads.html
- Iconset Homepage: http://graphicloads.com/product/flat-file-type-icons-vol-1
- License: Freeware
- Commercial usage: Allowed
- License info: License.txt http://www.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/filetype/License.txt
- Icons contained in set (13 icons)